# Laravel SSH put files to remote server

Tags: laravel, ssh

I am trying to upload a file from my laravel project to a remote server.

```
 $fileName = base_path().'/Storage/app/public/uploads/'.$file;
 SSH::into('production')->put($fileName, './');
```

The result is a blank screen with no errors or anything and the file is not on the remote server.  I know my ssh config is correct (keys and username/host stuff) because this works fine:

```
  SSH::into('production')->run('ls', function($line)
    {
        echo $line.PHP_EOL;
    });
```

What am i missing?  What can i do to see any verbose logging of the SSH call?

Comment: What is `SSH`? It's not part of Laravel.

Comment: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/remote

Comment: I mean, the obvious question is if you're running an SFTP server and what the logs show...